# Append Parameters to my current URL in GWT

Tags: url, gwt

Im implementing a jQuery widget on my app. I want that on load, the widget starts, and to make this i have to call my url with one parameter.

So, it would be like this MYURL/?param=value

Im doing this right now:

```
Window.Location.replace(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"?param=value");
```

And works fine, the problem is that reloads the app.

Is there a way to do this without refreshing my webpage?

Thank!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order not to reload the page, you have to modify just the hash fragment instead of the query string.

```java
Window.Location.replace(
   Window.Location.getPath() + Window.Location.getQueryString() +"#whatever");
```

In most browsers, though, there is a new mechanism called pushState so as you can change the url to whatever value without reloading the page. GWT does not have any wrapper for this yet, but you can use it through JSNI or, if you prefer to add [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) to your project, using this code:

```java
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

Properties history = JsUtils.prop(window, "history");
JsUtils.runJavascriptFunction(history, 
          "pushState", null, null, "whatever.html?foo=true");
```

FYI, the new [gwtproject](http://www.gwtproject.org/) web site is using this mechanism and gwtquery when navigating through the menu. The source code is in [gwt git](https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt-site-webapp/+/master/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/site/webapp/client/GWTProjectEntryPoint.java).

Comment: I tried to use Window.Location.replace(Window.Location.getPath() +"?walkme=11111"); but doesn works. Im doing it ok?

Comment: you cannot replace the location with a value which changes the querystring but the hashfragment. Change "?walkme=111" by "#walkme=111". Changing the querystring makes the browser reload the page unless you use pushstate.

Comment: What should i put in window?

Comment: window is the static variable `GQuery.window`. Updated the answer to include the import you have to use.

Comment: ok, it appends the values, but the action isnt executed. Why would it be?

Comment: The page is not reloaded, that is what you wanted to do. Now you have to code some action in your app to handle the action and do whatever you want with each url. In the case of the http://gwtproject.org they get the static html from the server via ajax and insert the content into a `div`.

Comment: What do mean, pushState does not work in chrome? It does work. If you open the developer tools you could have some problems though: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=101137. Post the not working code and I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

Use Window.location is not a proper way to do this as Philippe Beaudoin (i think he works for Google) said:

> From what I understand, modifying the browser URL without inserting a
>   token in the history is not supported by browsers. GWTP 0.4 will not
>   touch the URL (whereas 0.3 touched it, forcing you to insert a new
>   element in the history). Calling updateHistory() should have the exact
>   same effect as 0.3.
>
> I remember some people saying that they were able to modify the URL
>   without inserting an history token and without reloading the app by
>   calling Window.Location.replace() using the current url with a
>   modified hash fragment. However, this is not documented and I would be
>   surprised if it worked on all browsers.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-platform/glnowOS_8CM

In GWTP, you can do this very easily.

In GWTP, when you use eClipse to create a presenter say FirstPresenter, then eClipse will generate all necessary classes for you, these classes are: FirstPresenter.java, FirstView.java, FirstView.ui.xml

There some package (urproject.client.place) in Gwtp that help to manage all things to Place such as the param access, add mor param without refreshing the page.

In FirstPresenter.java, u first need to inject PlaceManager (put it outside the method) & then create a function saying addParam(String myParam):

```
    @Inject PlaceManager placeManager;

    public void addParam(String myParam, String myValue){
       PlaceRequest request = new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.yourNameToken).with(myParam, myValue);
      placeManager.updateHistory(request, true);
    }
```

Note:If you want >1 param, u can use as many `.with` as u want `.with(myParam, myValue).with(myParam2, myValue2)`. You can get param by `String val=request.getParameter(myParam,"");`. If you want to get param when the page got initialized then use this:

```
    @Override
     public void prepareFromRequest(PlaceRequest request){
    super.prepareFromRequest(request);
    String myVal=request.getParameter("myParam", "");
     }
```

That done. You must use Gwtp package to be able to use that function, Gwtp is the best framework i can suggest, they have a lot of powerful stuffs. You can't manage a very complicated web app by just using Gwt as Gwt is too limited & just for small app, but big web app require powerful framework & that is Gwtp. Not many people in Stackoverflow know Gwtp, so it hard to get answer but u can learn it by watching videos.

There're a very good videos for u to learn GWTP at youtube here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm-RO-cmsEQ&list=PL29DDDC847F63AF82

Hope this can help u

Comment: please, which would be the exact code. What to put in NameToken?
placeManager? I get an error in that line, obvisulty somthing is missing. Thanks!